# How to create unit tests with Apollo and Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, apollo

I'm staring up an Angular 5 project and it auto-generated some spec unit tests for my components and services.  For those components that require Apollo I'm getting an error `NullInjectorError: No provider for Apollo!`

I added the Apollo module to the import and declare section like so:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ContractsDashboardComponent, Apollo ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

However now I get the error

`Failed: Unexpected value 'Apollo' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.`

In the normal app I have a module `GraphQLModule` that calls `apollo.create` in the constructor.  Should I mock that somehow as well?

Answer (score 5):

If Apollo is a module, then you should import it.

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ Apollo ],
      declarations: [ ContractsDashboardComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

If it isn't a module, it should be a provider, so you need to provide it :

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ Apollo ],
      declarations: [ ContractsDashboardComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Because clearly, it isn't a component (the error requires it to have a component decorator), yet you put into the declarations.

Since your first error is `NullInjectorError: No provider for Apollo!`, I guess that Apollo is a service that you injected into your component, so you should use the second method, with the providing.

Comment: so I added ApolloModule to the providers and that seems to have cleared up one error - however now I get `StaticInjectorError[AuthService]: NullInjectorError: No provider for AuthService! ` which I'm assuming is needed by the route auth guard.  I tried just adding that to declarations as well but it didn't work.  Is this an easy fix or should I read up more on dependency injection with angular tests?

Comment: No, this means you have an injection in your constructor that is `private authService: AuthService`. To resolve this error, you need to provide your auth service by adding it to the list of providers. But since you're not testing it, you should **mock it**. To mock it, add this to your providers : `{ provide: AuthService, useValue: myMock }`. Now let's say your service has only one function `auth()` : then `myMock = { auth: () => XXX }`, where XXX must be typed the same as the result of `auth()`. If there's not only one function, you must add every other functions / variables to myMock.